# Arduino average result truncation dilemma

Tags: arduino, average

Can I truncate the code from this:

```
// Gather up samples from analog read
for (int i = 0; i < SAMPLE_NUMBER; i++) {
  adcSamples[i] = analogRead(AR_P0);
  // read from pin and store
  delay(10);  // wait 10 milliseconds
}

// Then, average all of those samples
for (int i = 0; i < SAMPLE_NUMBER; i++) {
  adcAverage += adcSamples[i];
  // add all samples up . . .
}
adcAverage /= SAMPLE_NUMBER;
// . . . average it w/ divide
```

To this... and still retain the same function? Or will the gathering of samples be interrupted?

```
// Gather up samples from analog read
for (int i = 0; i < SAMPLE_NUMBER; i++) {
  adcSamples[i] = analogRead(AR_P0);
  // read from pin and store
  delay(10);  // wait 10 milliseconds
  adcAverage += adcSamples[i];
  // add all samples up . . .
}
adcAverage /= SAMPLE_NUMBER;
// . . . average it w/ divide
```

I'm a complete newbie so... Thank you for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but unless you want the individual values then you could do this.

```
  // Gather up samples from analog read
  for (int i = 0; i < SAMPLE_NUMBER; i++) 
  {
    adcAverage += analogRead(AR_P0);  // read from pin and store
    delay(10);  // wait 10 milliseconds
  }
  adcAverage /= SAMPLE_NUMBER;        // . . . average it w/ divide
```

Comment: This will also gather up ALL the samples from analogread and average them?

Comment: Yes.  Looking back at it though you may have an issue with overflow if SAMPLE_NUMBER is large enough.  Each reading will be 255 and an int is 16 bits on an Arduino (check that?) so if `SAMPLE_NUMBER` is >256 it will cause an overflow.  If that's an issue just insert `adcAverage /= 2;` before the delay and delete that division line after the loop)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - I couldn't remember off the top of my head, thanks for correcting it.  so `SAMPLE_NUMBER` must be less than 63.